# Can LogCat print in reverse order?

Tags: android, logcat

I would like to see LogCat run the other way, printing the most recent output at the top.  Is this possible?  So far I have not been able to reverse the output.

Comment: You want to run it … backwards in time?

Comment: lol... no, just show the most recent line first, rather than last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to understand the ADB protocol - https://github.com/cstyan/adbDocumentation this is a great reference

Try mucking around the [source code](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#cZwlSNS7aEw/sdk/ddms/libs/ddmuilib/src/com/android/ddmuilib/logcat/LogPanel.java&q=logcat&exact_package=android&type=cs)? I'm sure with a couple of tweaks you can get this to work.  (Update: the link is dead - it was a link to logpanel which a developer sees)

Instead if your familiar with Python - you can write a script - based on this https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/build/android/adb_logcat_monitor.py

I agree, it is a nice feature that should be activated when "Time" is clicked. You can put up a [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20386) on [b.android.com](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list)

Comment: ⁻¹, because the answer is irrelevant to the question *(and I've no idea how it got chosen by the question author)*. What is "simulator"? The link is broken and the question author didn't mention any simulators. If you wanted the author to go use some "simulator", I think that entails some elaboration, especially given you say it won't work OOTB but requires some "tweaks". And what "clicked"? There's literally nothing to "click", `adb logcat` is a terminal command that you execute when a phone is connected via a usb cable to gather system logs.

Comment: Bro this is from 2011,  the latest code is here https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/qemu/+/refs/heads/aosp-emu-30-release 

when i used to work on the Android OS, our company built custom tools over logcat to filter logs. Vendors also had built similar tools which are not in the public domain. Im sure it can be done if you have the time

Comment: Sorry, but the answer being old is only a problem in the context of broken link. But it's not supposed to be a link-only answer, right? So the age shouldn't be a problem. However, the answer seems to imply some knowledge from the reader which I don't posses *(and it's not like the question have that, so Idk how its author understood the answer)*. So I have no slightest idea what the answer is talking about. I also don't understand why you posted a link to an emulator. I have a physical phone that I needed to get logs from, how is emulator going to help me?

Comment: To be clear: the reason I mentioned the broken link was just in case the link has some information that was supposed to clarify the answer. I don't know if that's true, and neither I can check it as the link is broken  So I had to mention that in my comment, to avoid a potential reply that the answer is unclear because the link had had screenshots and stuff that would clarity it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Linux, I think you could use [tac](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_tac.htm) for that.

Comment: It's more complicated than that. The reason to get logs in reverse is because `adb logcat` gathers the logs since the creation of the universe, but it is sooo slooow printing them *(for reference, I have it running rn and 22 days of logs being printed for 1.5 hours already and it still didn't stop)*. You need a lot of time go get to the most recent date. One possible way to solve that would be filtering by date. But the easiest one would be if `adb logcat` could simply print the logs reversed. Using `tac` completely beats the purpose because you still need to wait for `adb logcat` to finish.